# D3 not adding path to a group over a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, maps, geojson

I'm setting up a website as a project to visualise connections received by specific devices and would like to display this data on a map.

I managed to draw the map itself in D3 but I can't figure out how to draw individual lines, from the connection source to the destination, over the map.

I've tried the following code and other iterations taking inspiration from answers on this site and tutorials/examples.

The selection selects the correct DIV but when I look at the dev console in Chrome "lines" is still empty.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <title>Connection Visualiser</title>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333;
    }

    #map-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .map path {
        fill: #87B687;
        stroke: #777;
    }

    .graticule path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #eee;
    }

    .lines path {
        stroke: #f00;
        fill: crimson;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="feed">

    </div>

    <div id="map-container" width="100%" height="100%">
        <svg id="map" width="99%" height="99%">
            <g class="graticule">
                <path></path>
            </g>
            <g class="map"></g>
            <g class="lines"></g>
        </svg>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var geojson;
        var projection;

        var testFeature = {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"IP":"1.2.3.4"},"geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[0.1278, 51.5074], [-74.0059, 40.7128]]}}

        var geoGenerator = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();

        function drawMap() {

            // Update projection
            projection = d3['geoEquirectangular']()
            geoGenerator.projection(projection);

            projection
                .fitSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight], { type: "FeatureCollection", features: geojson.features })

            // Update world map
            var u = d3.select('g.map')
                .selectAll('path')
                .data(geojson.features)

            u.enter()
                .append('path')
                .merge(u)
                .attr('d', geoGenerator);

            // Update graticule
            d3.select('.graticule path')
                .datum(graticule())
                .attr('d', geoGenerator);

            // Draw an example line
            l = d3.select('g.lines')
                .selectAll('path')
                .data(testFeature)

            l.enter()
                .append('path')
                .merge(l)
                .attr("d", geoGenerator);
        }


        d3.json('/Maps/countries-coastline-10km.geo.json', function (err, json) {
            geojson = json;
            drawMap();
        })

        window.onresize = function () {
            drawMap();
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.data` must be an array, so, wrapping the `testFeature` with `[]` fixes the problem. Here it is formatted:

```
    var testFeature = [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "IP":"1.2.3.4"
        }, 
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [0.1278, 51.5074],
            [-74.0059, 40.7128]
          ]
        }
      }
    ];
```

Here is a preview of what I got.

[image]

If you make the following change it will look like below:

```
.lines path {
    stroke: #f00;
    fill: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't get an email for the reply! I hactually had figured it out, although I was using .datum() at first and still not getting the expected result...
I had the fill set to red to make sure I wasn't drawing the line and not seeing it!

Comment: I ended up going with Mapbox in the end. The performance is better, the map looks a bit better and it is draggable and zoomable with varying levels of detail by default!